# SSIS: Data Conversion Package failed

Tags: ssis

I was trying to load a table from Excel Source to SQL Server Destination with a data conversion transformation task using SSIS Package. but when I ran the package, it failed with the following error messages

```
===================================

Failure saving package. (Microsoft Visual Studio)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design.Serialization.DtrDesignerSerializer.SerializePackage(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, Package package, TextWriter textWriter)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design.Serialization.DtrDesignerSerializer.SerializeComponent(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, IComponent component, Object serializationStream)
   at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.Serialization.DesignerComponentSerializer.Serialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, Object value)
   at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.VsIntegration.Designer.Serialization.DataWarehouseDesignerLoader.Serialize()
   at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.VsIntegration.Designer.Serialization.BaseDesignerLoader.Flush(Boolean forceful)
   at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.VsIntegration.Designer.Serialization.BaseDesignerLoader.Flush()
   at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.VsIntegration.Designer.Serialization.DataWarehouseContainerManager.OnBeforeSave(UInt32 docCookie)

===================================

An invalid character was found in text content.
 (msxml6.dll)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package.SaveToXML(String& packageXml, IDTSEvents events)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design.Serialization.DtrDesignerSerializer.SerializePackage(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, Package package, TextWriter textWriter)

===================================

An invalid character was found in text content.
 (msxml6.dll)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSPackagePersist100.SavePackageToXML(Object& pvDestination, Boolean vbReturnDOM, IDTSEvents100 pEvents)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package.SaveToXML(String& packageXml, IDTSEvents events)
```

Comment: This error appears to be with saving the package and has nothing to do with Excel. Please post relevant error messages.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and found that the file I was attempting to import had a non-printing character at the end of the second header.  Removing this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looking to resolve this "urgently", I'll make both a short-term and long-term suggestion:

1) For the short-term, a practical approach:
Does it work, in your situation, to load the spreadsheet in sections?
Will it hurt anything, for you to re-try/re-do the load multiple times, to find the problem? 
Or, can you try this load in a test environment?

If so, then try loading the first-half, or the first-1/4, or first 10 rows, etc., until you find the row that's causing the problem.  At the very least, you can then load *everything but* that row... at best, maybe the problem will be easy to find, at that point.

2) For the long-term... do you (or somebody there) have access to *modifying* the SSIS package? 
If so, then I recommend coding error row redirection, within the Data Flow Task:  rows with problems go to another destination (red arrow), while rows without problems go to the usual destination (green arrow).

For more on error row redirection, see these links: 
 
A)  Intro:  [Handling Errors in Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141679%28SQL.90%29.aspx) 
 
B)  Some issues others have run into: 
[Programmatically configuring error and truncation dispositions for row redirection](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8ee55ea4-9d1f-4f34-b538-faa4735c8546/programmatically-configuring-error-and-truncation-dispositions-for-row-redirection?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

Hope that helps...

Comment: Ok Thanks will Try what you suggested as see how it goes. My biggest problem now is the SQL Server Destination Task. It still has the red sign after I have configured it

Comment: I have tried as you suggested and am getting the following error messages

Comment: @user3150352 -- (A) Your comment from 20 mins ago does not actually show the error messages.  (If they are too long, consider adding them as an "Update:", to the end of your question.)  (B) Please confirm:  are you trying point 2 (error-row redirection)?  (C) Did you try point 1 (partial loading to identify or avoid the error row)?  (D) Re' your first comment:  if the red sign is on your *Destination* task, that's a problem with SQL Server, not Excel.  If you've changed your Source object, and/or the metadata in the "green arrow", then the layout of the destination table needs to match that.